# Gulp project running locally but unable to build

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp

I am trying building a website with a clone from https://github.com/cssninjaStudio/krypton.

I can run the  project locally with `yarn run dev`  command working properly, but when i try to build the app to host in a VPS with `yarn build or yarn run prod` giving an error
`Task never defined: prod`

Here is my gulp.js

```
const del = require('del');
const options = require("./config");
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const bourbon = require('node-bourbon').includePaths;
const postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
const cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
const purgecss = require('gulp-purgecss');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const panini = require('panini');

const browserify = require("browserify");
const babelify = require("babelify");
const source = require("vinyl-source-stream");
const nodepath = 'node_modules/';

sass.compiler = require('sass');

//Note : Webp still not supported in major browsers including forefox
//const webp = require('gulp-webp'); //For converting images to WebP format
//const replace = require('gulp-replace'); //For Replacing img formats to webp in html
const logSymbols = require('log-symbols'); //For Symbolic Console logs :) :P 

//Load Previews on Browser on dev
function livePreview(done) {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: options.paths.dist.base
    },
    port: options.config.port || 5000
  });
  done();
}

//Copy latest installed Bulma
function setupBulma() {
  console.log("\n\t" + logSymbols.info, "Installing Bulma Files..\n");
  return src([nodepath + 'bulma/*.sass', nodepath + 'bulma/**/*.sass'])
    .pipe(dest('src/sass/'));
}

//Compile Sass code
function compileSASS() {
  console.log("\n\t" + logSymbols.info, "Compiling Bulma Sass..\n");
  return src(['src/sass/bulma.sass'])
    .pipe(sass({
      outputStyle: 'compressed',
      sourceComments: 'map',
      sourceMap: 'sass',
      includePaths: bourbon
    }).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
    .pipe(dest('dist/assets/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}

//Compile Scss code
function compileSCSS() {
  console.log("\n\t" + logSymbols.info, "Compiling App SCSS..\n");
  return src(['src/scss/main.scss'])
    .pipe(sass({
      outputStyle: 'compressed',
      sourceComments: 'map',
      sourceMap: 'scss',
      includePaths: bourbon
    }).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
    .pipe(dest('dist/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}

//Compile HTML partials with Panini
function compileHTML() {
  console.log("\n\t" + logSymbols.info, "Compiling HTML..\n");
  panini.refresh();
  return src('src/pages/**/*.html')
    .pipe(panini({
      root: 'src/pages/',
      layouts: 'src/layouts/',
      partials: 'src/partials/',
      helpers: 'src/helpers/',
      data: 'src/data/'
    }))
    .pipe(dest('dist'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}

//Concat CSS Plugins
function concatCssPlugins() {
  console.log("\n\t" + logSymbols.info, "Compiling Plugin styles..\n");
  return src([
    nodepath + 'simplebar/dist/simplebar.min.css',
    nodepath + 'plyr/dist/plyr.css',
    nodepath + 'codemirror/lib/codemirror.css',
    nodepath + 'codemirror/theme/shadowfox.css',
    'src/vendor/css/*',
  ])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(concat('app.css'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(dest('dist/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}

//Reset Panini Cache
function resetPages(done) {
  console.log("\n\t" + logSymbols.info, "Clearing Panini Cache..\n");
  panini.refresh();
  done();
}

//Triggers Browser reload
function previewReload(done) {
  console.log("\n\t" + logSymbols.info, "Reloading Browser Preview.\n");
  browserSync.reload();
  done();
}

//Development Tasks
function devHTML() {
  return src(`${options.paths.src.base}/**/*.html`).pipe(dest(options.paths.dist.base));
}

//Optimize images
function devImages() {
  return src(`${options.paths.src.img}/**/*`).pipe(dest(options.paths.dist.img));
}

// Let's write our task in a function to keep things clean
function javascriptBuild() {
  // Start by calling browserify with our entry pointing to our main javascript file
  return (
    browserify({
      entries: [`${options.paths.src.js}/main.js`],
      // Pass babelify as a transform and set its preset to @babel/preset-env
      transform: [babelify.configure({ presets: ["@babel/preset-env"] })]
    })
      // Bundle it all up!
      .bundle()
      // Source the bundle
      .pipe(source("bundle.js"))
      // Then write the resulting files to a folder
      .pipe(dest(`dist/js`))
  );
}

function copyFonts() {
  console.log("\n\t" + logSymbols.info, "Copying fonts to dist folder.\n");
  return src([
    'src/fonts/*',
  ])
    .pipe(dest('dist/fonts'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}


//Copy data files
function copyData() {
  console.log("\n\t" + logSymbols.info, "Copying data files..\n");
  return src([
    'src/data/**/*',
  ])
    .pipe(dest('dist/data'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}

function watchFiles() {
  //watch('src/**/*.html', compileHTML);
  watch(`${options.paths.src.base}/**/*.html`, series(compileHTML, previewReload));
  watch(['src/scss/**/*', 'src/scss/*'], compileSCSS);
  watch(`${options.paths.src.js}/**/*.js`, series(javascriptBuild, previewReload));
  watch(`${options.paths.src.img}/**/*`, series(devImages, previewReload));
  console.log("\n\t" + logSymbols.info, "Watching for Changes..\n");
}

function devClean() {
  console.log("\n\t" + logSymbols.info, "Cleaning dist folder for fresh start.\n");
  return del([options.paths.dist.base]);
}


exports.setup = series(setupBulma);

exports.default = series(
  devClean, // Clean Dist Folder
  resetPages,
  parallel(copyFonts, concatCssPlugins, compileSCSS, javascriptBuild, devImages, compileHTML),
  livePreview, // Live Preview Build
  watchFiles // Watch for Live Changes
);
```

Need some help to build this website and host it in VPS

Many Thanks in Advance

Comment: There readMe file says that you should run : npm run dev after installing dependencies.

Comment: npm run dev is working fine locally, but when i close the terminal the application is also switching off

Comment: orelse wanted to run the command ```npm run dev``` in the background, so the app works continuously even after i kill the terminal

Comment: If you want to create prod build, you can run gulp prod instead as per their package.json script tag.

Comment: after running the gulp prod it giving me an error task never defined: prod

Answer (score 0):

The prod task is not define within the Gulp file. The dev task is, because it is calling the default gulp task (gulp with no arg is calling the default which is found at the end of the gulp file

```
exports.default = series(
  devClean, // Clean Dist Folder
  resetPages,
  parallel(copyFonts, concatCssPlugins, compileSCSS, javascriptBuild, devImages, compileHTML),
  livePreview, // Live Preview Build
  watchFiles // Watch for Live Changes
);
```

Take a look at your package.json file, this is were the script name are define (such as dev and prod.)

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "gulp",
    "build": "gulp prod",
    "prod": "gulp prod",
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
  },
```

So you should create a prod method in your gulp.js and should only call usefull method for prod env (remove livePreview and watch, you are most likely only build and deploy.)

I prefer to task definition like this,

```
gulp.task("prod", function (callback) {
    config.runCleanBuilds = true;

    return runSequence(
        "taskA",
        "taskB",
        "taskC",     
        callback);
});
```

but you could do it the same way they do in their gulp file I guess

```
exports.prod = series(
  devClean, // Clean Dist Folder
  resetPages,
  parallel(copyFonts, concatCssPlugins, compileSCSS, javascriptBuild, devImages, compileHTML)
);
```